# Creating a Regular Expression for language that emphasises order

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'm trying to create a regular expression for a language that follows {A,B,C} and that for every valid string produced, it must follow the order of A followed by B followed by C. Hence, the valid strings are

```
A,AB,ABC,ABCA,ABCAB,ABCABC...
```

I'm thinking of something like:

```
A(BC*)*
```

but it accepts strings like

```
ABAB
```

which is unaccepted. Would appreciate some help on this as I'm terrible at figuring out regex.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a parser? It seems you need a CFG for this, not sure regex is going to do it.

Comment: Why is `AB` and `ABCABC` valid but `ABAB` is invalid?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Regex is required not parsers.

Comment: @anubhava because it has to go through a 'C' before followed by another A,B and so on

Comment: Is `BC` a valid input?

Comment: @anubhava no. A always come first before B.

Comment: How about [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/cbANTo/2)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for your job:

```
^(?:ABC)*A(?:BC?)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r8ZSy8/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:ABC)*`: Match zero or more occurrences of `ABC`
- `A`: Match letter `A`
- `(?:BC?)?`: Followed by `B` or `BC`
- `$`: End

Comment: @Do you mind writing it in the normal form with just parentheses, Kleene's star, conjunction or disjunctions?

Comment: Sure, you can use capturing groups: `^(ABC)*A(BC?)?$`

Comment: would there be any alternatives to the ? and $ and ^ since i have not encountered it in my syllabus yet? In your line of regex above, removing ? and $ and ^, in that form is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You have to put some effort in learning regex in that case. If you want a regex then you cannot avoid anchors `^` and `$` and also `?` is used for optional matching (required for this regex)